# listagg DB link issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, dblink, listagg, ora-00923

For below query, I am only getting error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected when in DBLINK.

```
select LISTAGG(SERVICE_ORDER, ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SERVICE_ORDER) 
"service_order"
FROM TBL_DATA@TBL_REP
```

Comment: Works just fine for me on 11gR2 (copy/pasted your query, changed column, table and database link names).

Comment: hi thank you,  I saw it.. it was on 10g, and my db is 11g. Thanks.

Comment: Aha. LISTAGG won't work on 10g as it doesn't exist in that version. You can use XMLAGG or (undocumented) WM_CONCAT.

Comment: I will use the ones you've suggested. Thank you very much mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Works on 12c(12.1.0.2.0), too:

```
SELECT LISTAGG (SERVICE_ORDER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SERVICE_ORDER)
           "service_order"
  FROM (SELECT 'a' SERVICE_ORDER FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b' SERVICE_ORDER FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'c' SERVICE_ORDER FROM DUAL)
```